# How to iterate the each element of the list to multiply the specific columns to get new calculated columns

Tags: python, pandas

How to iterate each element of the list to multiply the specific columns to get new calculated columns.

```
List= [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
```

Pandas Dataframe(df) has one column called `A0`.

I need to calculate four additional columns.

Say to calculate `A1`, I need to use `(1+1st [list value])* A0`

```
(1+0.1)*1 , (1+0.1)*2, (1+0.1)*3, (1+0.1)*4
```

To calculate `A2`, I need to use `(1+2nd [list value])* A1`

etc

As below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L53bc.jpg)

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Idea is use numpy - convert list to 1d array, add `1` with cumulative product and add to column `A0`, last convert to `DataFrame` and add to original column:

So if no loop solution performance is increased if large DataFrame.

```
List= [0.1 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A0':range(1, 6)})

arr = df['A0'].to_numpy()[:, None] * np.cumprod(np.array(List) + 1)

c = [f'A{x + 1}' for x in range(len(List))]
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=c))
print (df)
   A0   A1    A2     A3       A4
0   1  1.1  1.32  1.716   2.4024
1   2  2.2  2.64  3.432   4.8048
2   3  3.3  3.96  5.148   7.2072
3   4  4.4  5.28  6.864   9.6096
4   5  5.5  6.60  8.580  12.0120
```

Comment: I was trying to solve this with a loop but this solution is way better.